# target="_blank" not opening new tab with "mailto:" link

Tags: email, hyperlink, mailto

I have a link on my website where you click and it opens up your email and starts a new draft. However, I've been testing it, and it opens email in the same tab, which is kind of annoying because then you have to reopen the page. I have target="_blank", but it still doesn't open in a new tab.

```html
<button class="navhome" onclick="window.location.href='mailto:info.awolindustries@gmail.com'" 
    target="_blank" style="background-color:rgb(0,255,0);
    border:none;
    color:white;
    padding:15px 32px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:16px;">Contact us</button>
```

Does `target:"_blank"` not work for buttons, or is it that I'm using `mailto`, which doesn't necessarily use a browser?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a underscore before the name of the link type, like this: `target = '_blank'` or `target = "_blank"`
**EDIT**: It is also because you can only have links in anchor tags like so `<a href = "link.com" target = "_blank">Click to go somewhere</a>`. Sorry for missing that.

Comment: That still doesn't work. I think you're right about needing an "_", but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by that? How can I change it?

Comment: Just change the button to an anchor tag